# How to prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int^\pi_0 \pi f(nx)g(x)\ \mathrm {d}x = \int^\pi_0 f(x)\ \mathrm {d}x \int^\pi_0 g(x)\ \mathrm {d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, definite-integrals, periodic-functions

**Question**

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb {R}$ such that $f(x + \pi) = f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb {R}$. Prove that, if $g$ is a continuous function on $[0, \pi]$, then $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int^\pi_0 \pi f(nx)g(x)\ \mathrm {d}x = \int^\pi_0 f(x)\ \mathrm {d}x \int^\pi_0 g(x)\ \mathrm {d}x.$$

---

This question just appeared in my final calculus examination this afternoon and I could not do it ):. I am just really bad at proofs. However, on reading the question, the condition of $f(x + \pi) = f(x)$ on $f$ tells me that $f$ must be some kind of periodic function and I see $\pi$ all around, so I am guessing we will have to make use of some trigonometry. Any intuitive explanations as to how the equality can be proven will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you sure about the given question? Because if you take $g(x)=1$ and $f(x)=x^2 \: ,-\pi \leq x \leq \pi$  and extend it periodically to whole of $\mathbb{R}$ then the left hand side is $\pi \int_{0}^{\pi} n^2 x^2dx = \frac{n^2(\pi)^4}{3}$ whose limit does not exist when $n \rightarrow \infty$ whereas the right hand side is a finite number.

Comment: @nrynn If you define $f$ this way $f(0)=0\neq \pi^2=f(\pi)$.

Comment: @PAM1499 yes you are right. I made a mistake. The definition of $f(x)$ should be this. $f(x)= x^2\:,\frac{-\pi}{2}\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @nrynn It seems you did not use the extended function in your left hand integral computation.

Comment: @DavidMitra yes I didn't. I just wanted to ensure the function $f$ met the required conditions in the question but the computation required only to know what happens in $[0,\pi]$

Comment: This may work: partition $[0,\pi]$ into $n$ subintervals of equal length. On each subinterval $[m\pi/n, (m+1)\pi/n]$ $g$ is approximately constant, say $g\approx g(m\pi/n)$ there. Then,  using the periodicity of $f$ and the substitution $u=nx$: $$\int_{m\pi/n}^{(m+1)\pi/n}\pi f(nx) g(x)\,dx\approx\int_0^\pi f(u)\,du\cdot g(m\pi/n)\cdot{\pi\over n}$$ Sum up these terms (over $m$), on the RHS factor out $\int_0^\pi f(u)\,du$, and recognize the other factor as a Riemann sum for $\int_0^\pi g(x)\,dx$. Of course, you will have to make things rigorous.

Comment: @DavidMitra do you think nrynn counterexample is not valid? Because it seems fine to me although I believe that should be a $2$ factor multiplying the value of the integral.

Comment: @pam1499 The integrand is bounded by $\pi\cdot\pi^2/4$. As $x$ ranges from 0 to $\pi$, $nx$ ranges through several periods of $f$. Right?

Comment: Ohh of course. I completely forget nrynn defined $f$ as a periodic extension. I see your point now. Sorry for bothering!

Comment: @DavidMitra Oh I get it now. The integral I computed is wrong. Sorry, I didn't understand your previous comment and thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you for the discussion! Would you mind putting your idea into a more detailed answer, so that I can better analyse it? I do not quite understand your approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $N$ so that whenever $|x-y|<\pi/N$, we have $|f(nx)g(x)-f(nx)g(y)|<\epsilon/\pi$. This can be done since both $f$ and $g$ are uniformly continuous functions.

Now, for $n\ge N$

$$\eqalign{
\int_0^\pi \pi f(nx)g(x)\,dx&= \sum_{m=1}^n \int_{(m-1)\pi/n}^{m\pi/n}\pi f(nx)g(x)\,dx\cr
&\le\sum_{m=1}^n \Bigl[{\epsilon\over\pi}\cdot{\pi\over n}
+\int_{(m-1)\pi/n}^{m\pi/n} \pi f(nx) g(m\pi/n)\,dx\Bigr]\cr
&=\epsilon +\sum_{m=1}^n\Bigl[ g(m\pi/n) \int_{(m-1)\pi}^{m\pi} {\pi\over n}f(u)\,du\Bigr]\cr
&=\epsilon +\sum_{m=1}^n \Bigl[g(m\pi/n)\cdot{\pi\over n} \int_0^\pi f(x)\,dx\Bigr]\cr
&=\epsilon + \int_0^\pi f(x)\, dx \cdot\Bigl[\sum_{m=1}^n g(m\pi/n) \cdot{\pi\over n}\Bigr]
}$$

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary,
taking limits of both sides of the above gives
$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^\pi \pi f(nx)g(x)\,dx \le \int_0^\pi f(x)\,dx \cdot\int_0^\pi g(x)\, dx.$$
In a similar manner, ones shows
$$
\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^\pi \pi f(nx)g(x)\,dx \ge \int_0^\pi f(x)\,dx \cdot\int_0^\pi g(x)\, dx,
$$
whence the result follows.